# Loader image on AJAX call is not displaying on mobile screen but properly working in desktop screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am showing a loader (.gif) using div tag in AJAX call. It is working in desktop screens but when I run the same code in mobile screen, it just displays white screen as a loader and not .gif.

```
<div id="loader" style="display: none;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('.view_data').click(function(){  
           var id = $(this).attr("id");
           $.ajax({  
                url:"abc.php",  
                method:"post",  
                data:{id:id},
                beforeSend: function(){
                  // Show image container
                  $("#loader").show();
                },   
                success:function(data){  
                     // Do something  
                },
                complete: function(){
                  // Hide image container
                  $("#loader").hide();
                }  
           });
      });  
 }); 
</script>

#loader{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('../../img/loader_ajax.gif');
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.8);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to test in mobile offline like localhost, If you that then wouldn't work!

Comment: I am working on server.

Comment: This is working on firefox mobile also, only chrome is creating problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could We have the link of your project?

Comment: check it out in the chrome mobile developer tool. I hope you would get your solution.

Comment: How to check chrome mobile developer... Can you help me?

Comment: there is every thing correct! Share the bug's images with us quickly to sever you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved... I applied inline css and use img tag for gif inside div tag for mobile screen pages. The problem is in background-image: url() in chrome for mobile.